# Implicit function of two variables with no integer pair solutions; or, rational points on projective varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-varieties

I was originally going to ask this question on MO, but it's unfortunately a little vague and is not a thorough presentation of any of my own work.

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Under what conditions does $f(x,y)=0$ have no solutions $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$? I understand this question is deceivingly difficult and is essentially asking about rational points on projective varieties. I have made no progress further than the trivial cases; for instance, any horizontal shift or integer vertical shifts of: $$f(x,y)=x^2y+y^2x+3y^3-y-1$$
Is one such set of functions satisfying my condition, although does not provide nearly any insight into the general solution to this problem.

**My question:** while not a specific 'reference request,' I would like to know of any electronically published/readily available work done on this or a similar problem. Or, if anyone could provide insight toward approaching this problem, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: This is basically [Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem). The solution is that there are no general algorithms for determining whether such a polynomial has integer solutions. Try searching about integer solutions of diophantine equations: this is a well-studied area of math.

Comment: The example you gave is a curve of genus $1$, and can be given the structure of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$: its minimal model is $y^2 - y = x^3 - 2 x^2 + x - 3$. There are many resources on finding rational and integral points on elliptic curves, such as Silverman and Silverman and Tate, so you could start there.